# MySQL Escapes field's default value when selecting from COLUMN_DEFAULT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, escaping

I am creating a table field with default value including quotes and slashes, for example:

```
;:'",./\?<`>
```

It works as expected when I create new records without specifying that field - it gets exactly the same value that I can reqd with SQL select:

```
;:'",./\?<`>
```

But when I read default value directly from system db.table.field `information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT` I get escaped value:

```
;:''",./\\?<`>'
```

Note, that `'` is doubled `''` and `\` also got one more escaping slash `\\`.

So I wonder, how is this escaping is called and how can I unescape it and get original value? Will something like this be sufficient?

```
val = val.replace("''", "'").replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

As addition to the question: I am writing my application in `nodejs` so if anyone happen to know a package that can help me with unescaping I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Where/how are you viewing the output from the select?  I think it you were to write it to a file, then you would not see this problem with escaping.  I propose that the escaping is only there so that your eye knows that it is a literal single quote, and not the marker for a string literal.

Comment: I am not sure: I am seing this escaped output both in my mysql client SQLyog and when I select COLUMN_DEFAULT in my nodejs app. And it is so only for this coumn, rows created in that table (w/o specifying this field, defaulted to that value) and selected with either way - come out in original form.